# Sorting wrt to a column value in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, dataset, columnsorting

I have multiple columns in my dataset and column 2 contains value from 1 till 7. I want to sort my dataset with respect to second column . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you need is [`sortrows`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)

By default this sorts with respect to the first column, but an additional argument can be used to change this to the 2nd (or 5th, 17th etc)

If `A` is your original array:

`B = sortrows(A,2);`

will give you the sorted array B w.r.t 2nd column

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked

Comment: if I want to separate my dataset for all the values of 2nd column. How would I do that? Means I want separate dataset when value of 2nd column is 1 ,2 ,3 and so on.

Answer (score -2):

What did you mean by sort with respect to second column? You should be more specific or at least give us an example.
If you need a simple sort on each column use the following

```
    A =
    95    45    92    41    13     1    84
    23     1    73    89    20    74    52
    60    82    17     5    19    44    20
    48    44    40    35    60    93    67
    89    61    93    81    27    46    83
    76    79    91     0    19    41     1
```

Sort each column of A in ascending order:

```
    c = sort(A, 1)
    c =
    23     1    17     0    13     1     1
    48    44    40     5    19    41    20
    60    45    73    35    19    44    52
    76    61    91    41    20    46    67
    89    79    92    81    27    74    83
    95    82    93    89    60    93    84
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped